# Using RDFLib to extract non RDF data as RDF data from webpages

Tags: rdf, virtuoso, rdflib, n-triples

I recently installed the RDFLib to work with RDF data. I want to extract RDF data from any webpage with non-RDF/RDF data, like Virtuoso Sponger

[like this link does] (http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/html/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1)

and store as a N-Triples(nt) or N3/Turtle format(as on the options in the link footer). I get warnings and errors if I perform

```
 g.parse("http://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1.html",format="n3")
```

Also is there an inbuilt functionality for ontology mapping with RDFLib?

Comment: Can you refine what you mean with "functionality for ontology mapping"?

Answer (score 0):

> I get warnings and errors if I perform
>
> ```
> g.parse("http://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1.html",format="n3")
> ```

This is not really surprising as you're essentially asking it to parse an HTML page with the n3 parser.

You could run

```
g.parse("http://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1.html", format="html")
```

but this is probably not what you want either. RDFLib can work with RDF that is embedded in HTML (like RDFa or microdata) and it can also extract some "general purpose RDF" from HTML, but the results are pretty different from what you get back from uriburner. The reason is that it uses a custom "slideshare" Virtuoso Sponger for which is tailored to extract a lot more useful information from the slideshare HTML. If you want to use that knowledge which was put into the special sponger, you could query the page "through" uriburner by parsing the RDF version from uriburner (the link can be found on the bottom of [the page](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/html/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1)):
[image: How to find the link]

```
g.parse(
    'http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2Fkleinerperkins%2Finternet-trends-v1&query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkeddata.uriburner.com%2Fabout%2Fid%2Fentity%2Fhttp%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2Fkleinerperkins%2Finternet-trends-v1%3E&output=text%2Frdf%2Bn3',
    format='n3'
)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you @Hees. Also do you have any idea about my second question, about the ontology?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to your question it is quite unclear to me what functionality you're searching for. RDFLib (as its name suggests) is mostly about working with RDF.

Comment: @Hees I think I am able to get what i want thanks to your g.parse line. 
1. Could you please explain how you formed this link, like after the sparql part, the link is too long while the initial link just contained kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1.html.
2. Also if I need the data as xml, I tried to write format='n3', but got multiple errors, so if i need in an xml format (basically to get tags) how do I go about it?

Comment: 1. i copy pasted if from the bottom of the uriburner page (see screenshot)
2. well, if you need xml you obviously need to specify `format='xml'` and copy the XML link from uriburner...

Comment: Ok, got it, so I did not want to open up the page on the browser and just get the data, but in this approach I would have to manually go to the bottom of the page to get the link. Any other possible solution to get a link (n3/xml) without manually accessing the page?